# Jenkins - Execute Shell as a post build action

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to use the "Execute shell" from the 'build action' as a post-build task. Is that possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you are looking for [PostBuild Script Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PostBuildScript+Plugin). After install this plugin, you can add post-action "Execute Shell" by following these steps:

> Add post-build action -->Execute a set of scripts --> Add build Step --> Execute Shell.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, as of June 2017, it seems that the `PostBuildScript` plugin has been suspended: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PostBuildScript+Plugin

Comment: The plugin seems to be back, as of October 2020.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah that is possible through one plugin [postbuild-task](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task). Through this you can run shell or batch scripts after build step also.